# Explanation of draw(_:) ios method syntax

Tags: swift

What does the `(_:for:)` syntax mean after the `draw` text? In particular the underscore and `for`. I would assume the two colons are meant to represent that the method takes two arguments.

I just picked this method as an example from https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1621844-draw

Additionally, there is a method `draw(_:)` and how does this differ from `draw(_:for:)`?

This is from https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622529-draw

I am unable to clearly discern what the differences are from reading the documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1- `draw(_:for:)`

> Implemented to draw the view’s content for printing.

2-  `draw(_:)`

> Draws the receiver’s image within the passed-in rectangle.

1- The **_** is the argument label and when it exists for a parameter you don't need to pass the parameter name when you call the method

e.x

```
func goTo(value:Int)  // call goTo(value:5)
func goTo(_ value:Int)  // call goTo(5)
```

2- The colon **:** separates the parameterName from the parameterType like

> paramterName:parameterType

Comment: Ok thanks - I understand that there are differences bw the 2 methods so I'm more asking about the formatting of how they're listed. So, what you're saying is when there is an underscore after the parentheses for a method, that underscore represents an optional parameter that doesn't necessarily need to be passed to the method?

Comment: @user2603139 when you write _ you can't type parameter name check **Function Argument Labels and Parameter Names** section  in https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Functions.html

Comment: “The colon `:` separates the parameterName from the parameterType like” ... Yes, where you implement the method, it separates the parameter name from the parameter type. But in the `draw(_:for:)` and `draw(_:)` syntax that the OP was asking about, this syntax we see in documentation, the colon obviously serves a completely different purpose, i.e. it now it namely it follows each argument label, e.g. `draw(_:for:)` has two parameters, the first has no argument label (indicated by the `_`) and the second parameter’s argument label is `for`. The colon in this case follows each argument label.

Comment: @Rob we should admit that this short re-cap of method they do is misleading when you look to it at the first time , they give it as a quick pre-look to the actual syntax as a mini-header function where number of colons is useful for knowing number of parameters and whether it has _ s or not  BTW it's a documentation style that should be ignored when it's time for a newbie to learn

Comment: Agreed. I was just pointing out that the OP was asking about what the `draw(_:for:)` syntax meant, with its confusing use of colons, and you proceeded to explain a completely unrelated use of a colon. Lol.